# set image from qtablewidget cell into Qlabel qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

I have a `QTablewidget` containing images and data in its cell. My goal is to set the image from `tablewidget` into `Qlabel`.

I'm trying to set image using

```cpp
ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap(ui->tableWidget->item(row, col)->text()))
```

Comment: The piece of code shown will try to create a [`QPixmap`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpixmap.html#QPixmap-2) from the `QString` supplied as a file path.  Is that really what you want?  If not then please provide more information and, preferably, a [mcve].

Comment: What is your question?